# Cant mount GlusterFS volume on EC2 client

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, network-share, mount, glusterfs

After a few days of trial and error I have successfully created my gluster volume on an EC2 instance (a single one at the moment) and it is successfully started…

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-10-26-7E ec2-user]# gluster volume info

Volume Name: gv0
Type: Distribute
Status: Started
Number of Bricks: 1
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: ec2-107-20-245-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/export
```

From my client EC2 instance I have installed gluster and fuse - however when I try to mount the drive I just continually get this error.

```
[root@ip-10-202-210-190 glusterfs]# mount -t glusterfs upload.themixtapesite.com:/gv0 /var/www/vhosts/i-16852366/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-9e5dc27086c8b2fd2e48678e1f54f98c/2013/02/gluster
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.
```

All required ports are open in the security group 111, 24007, 24008, 24009 on TCP and UDP just to make sure. Ive disabled selinux on the gluster server just in case it was that. I've even tried to do a "gluster peer probe" from the server to the intended client and it sees it and adds it to its list just fine.

Here are the log errors

```
[2013-06-13 06:24:41.022793] I [glusterfsd.c:1666:main] 0-/usr/sbin/glusterfs: Started running /usr/sbin/glusterfs version 3.3.1
[2013-06-13 06:24:41.041254] E [socket.c:1715:socket_connect_finish] 0-glusterfs: connection to  failed (No route to host)
[2013-06-13 06:24:41.041346] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1787:mgmt_rpc_notify] 0-glusterfsd-mgmt: failed to connect with remote-host: Transport endpoint is not connected
[2013-06-13 06:24:41.041372] I [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1790:mgmt_rpc_notify] 0-glusterfsd-mgmt: -1 connect attempts left
[2013-06-13 06:24:41.041641] W [glusterfsd.c:831:cleanup_and_exit] (-->/usr/lib64/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_transport_notify+0x28) [0x3ae580b018] (-->/usr/lib64/libgfrpc.so.0(rpc_clnt_notify+0xc0) [0x3ae580f$
[2013-06-13 06:24:41.041684] I [fuse-bridge.c:4648:fini] 0-fuse: Unmounting '/var/www/vhosts/i-16852366/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-9e5dc27086c8b2fd2e48678e1f54f98c/2013/02/gluster'.
```

So it obviously can't connect, but I don't know why - I've tried rebooting. Something else obvious I'm missing? Some extra linux software blocking something? I been through about 6 how to guides and tried every step, but nothing.

UPDATE: I can successfully SSH from the client instance to the gluster server instance - so they talk via SSH just fine, but still no luck mounting.

Both the server and the client have GlusterFS v 3.3.1-15 running.

Comment: I you move the destination server into a security group with all traffic allowed from source server does it work?

Comment: @golemwashere I made it so that the other security group was named and gave it access to ALL ports, which should be the same thing - but I will try to put them in the same security group now, just for arguments sake.

Comment: Ok @golemwashere I cloned the ami and launched it from the same security group as the client, but it made no difference, won't mount, same error log - I don't understand why other people have managed to do this. I wonder if theres something with my linux distro's ? Both are running Centos6.4

Comment: You've adjusted the security groups -- is there a firewall up on your server? --> service iptables stop

Comment: Nope, no firewall, ran the command on both server and client just in case though, no change :/

Comment: OK, what version of glusterfs are you using?

Comment: All right, I just fired up a pair of CentOS instances on EC2 to test this. Wide open security groups, following the quick start at: http://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/QuickStart, except I didn't create a separate xfs disk, and I only have one brick, so I skipped a few steps in the middle. My volume mounted as expected. I did get an error just like yours, but "service iptables stop" on the server fixed that. GlusterFS v3.3.1, CentOS 6.4, using the public DNS. Retrace your steps, this does work.

Comment: I'm using v 3.3.1-15 - I updated both client and server to them yesterday. I will try again - if I was doing something wrong formatting the EBS volume etc, that would show up early in the process when I tried to mount it on the server right?

Comment: Well I just tried "service iptables stop" on the server again but nothing, same issue. When you say "wide open security groups" what do you mean? Do you have a note of which AMI you booted, I will try to start again with the same server AMI you used perhaps...

Comment: I'm using this image: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00A6KUVBW. By wide open, I mean allow all icmp, all udp, all tcp -- just all open to eliminate closed ports as a problem

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try with the official image now, with only gluster installed. So you opened All TCP, all UDP and all ICMP to 0,0,0,0. Once its running I presume you deleted these options and set back to 24007, 24008, 24009 and 111 for security reasons and it still worked?

Comment: So just to emulate you EXACTLY here - can you link me to the repo you used? Ive attached a 20gb EBS mounted at /dev/sdb in Centos the drives display as XVD* instead, I have XVDE and XVDF so I'm going to assume the latter is my EBS volume? - and run everything on XVDF.

Comment: Its worked Jason! Official clean Centos seems to be answer, also I'm sure there were some more steps/different file system set up bits in that tutorial. Now I need FFMpeg on this server too, I'm presuming there is no reason that can't be installed with Gluster right? Thanks for testing with the Centos official releases thats the reason I got there in the end really - hopefully I can expand easily now - I think it might cost more to use official CentOS package though. Do you want to put this as an answer so I can vote for it?